# dlopen /proc/self/auxv: Permission denied RHEL6

Tags: c++, dlopen, rhel6

I have an executable that  need to load an .so file.

Everything is working on Ubunto and RHEL5 but on RHEL6 I'm getting this error on dlopen:
/proc/self/auxv: Permission denied

If I'm running the executable with root it is working without this error message.

void *handle = dlopen(file_path.c_str(), RTLD_LAZY | RTLD_GLOBAL);

Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7 (Santiago)

kernel: 2.6.32-573.26.1.el6.x86_64

gcc (GCC) 4.4.7

ldd (GNU libc) 2.12

What does this file stands for and is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: Which versions of the C library and of the kernel? Please **edit your question** to improve it. See also [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

Comment: I have updated the question, please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: You don't give your libc version. Perhaps you might try [musl-libc](http://musl-libc.org/). Also, did you ask your sysadmin (or support)? Probably something can be configured to give access to `/proc/self/auxv` without root permission. On my Debian system, I can access it.

Comment: Adedd ldd (GNU libc) 2.12 to the question, i will check on the permission issue.

Comment: Your kernel and libc are really old; I would suggest to upgrade your distribution to something more recent (current RHEL is at least 7). Otherwise, call your support line.

Comment: Another thing is that my .so file is using libproc, may this cases this error?

Comment: No, `/proc/self/auxv` is provided by the kernel. I strongly recommend upgrading your system.